# Bash. Inherit functions scopes

Tags: bash, scope

уI need a global counter and function which returns numbers one by one. For example I want this script to echo 6,7,8 (but it echo 6,6,6):

```
#!/bin/bash

port_counter=5

function get_free_port {
    port_counter=$((port_counter + 1))
    echo ${port_counter}
}

function foo {
    echo $(get_free_port)
}

foo
foo
(foo;)&
```

How can I obtain 6,7,8?

**UPDATE:**
Ok, after chepner's answer I need to specify a little my question. 
If I need to use `get_free_port` as variable in `foo`, I can't use this approach, isn't it?
So I can't write

```
function foo {
    variable=get_free_port # variable=$(get_free_port) was ok, but returns 6,6,6
    echo ${variable}
}
```

Also `foo &` - like usages is hardly desirable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't modify variables from a subprocess (which is what `$(...)` runs). You don't need one in this case:

```
function foo {
    get_free_port
}
```

However, for the same reason, you cannot call `foo` from a subshell or background job, either. Neither `foo &`, `(foo)`, nor `(foo)&` will update the value of `port_counter` in the current shell.

If you really need to call `get_free_port` *and* capture its output, you'll need to use a temporary file. For example:

```
foo () {
    get_free_port > some_temp_file
    cat some_temp_file
}
```

If this is not suitable, you may need to rethink your script's design.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. It push me to specify my question to describe problem deeply.

Comment: Updated, but I suspect your example is too simplified to convey your real problem. Why do you need to capture the output of a function when that output is simply the value of a global variable that you can already access directly?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just use this variable often in the same way and try to DRY. My really problem - I need to start lots of java-processes (quantity is dynamic) and all of them need different ports. So I need `free port generator` for it.

Comment: You could use `$((port_counter+=1))` in place of the function, which would increment `port_counter` (initialize it to a smaller value than you want to start with) and expand to the new value.

Answer (score 1):

The below code would give you the desired behavior:

```
#!/bin/bash

port_counter=5

function get_free_port {
    port_counter=$(( port_counter + 1 ))
    echo ${port_counter}
}

function foo {
    get_free_port 
# $(get_free_port) spawns a subshell and the parent shell variables are not
# available in the subshell.
}

foo #runs fine
foo #runs fine
foo #(foo;)& again spawns a subshell and the parent shell pariables are not available here.
```